# select the first child in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach

I have a `table` of elements that are coming from a loop. I need to select the first child of `class="test"`(All the elements have the same class because of loop). I wrote a jquery to select the child on page load but it selects the last child since all of them are coming from a loop. `jQuery(".test").trigger('click');`. Please help me through it. Thanks..

Comment: you need to share the loop and related code

Comment: `jQuery(".test").first().trigger('click');`

Comment: `jQuery(".test:first").trigger('click');`

Comment: @Arun P Johny jQuery(".test").first().trigger('click'); works great Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery [first-child-selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
jQuery(".test:first-child").trigger('click');
```

Comment: `first-child` will select the first child inside `.test` and not the `.test` itself

Comment: @Tushar I guess both do the same job, only difference is _:first matches only a single element, :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent._

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
jQuery(".test:first-child").trigger('click');
```

Or:

```
jQuery(".test").first().trigger('click');
```

Or:

```
jQuery(".test").eq(0).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write like

```
jQuery(".test:first-child").trigger('click');
```

For your reference https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
jQuery(".test:first").trigger('click');
```